# PHP code for validate AU post code using preg_match

Tags: php

Hello I need to validate Australian post code length 4 digits. Therefore I wrote PHP code using  preg_match, but it did not work for me. Could you please tell me why my code is not working. This is my PHP code.

```
$value=(explode(",",$_POST['search']));
$value = preg_split('/[0-9]+\./', $_POST['search'], -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);


if (empty($value))
{
echo "<p >Please type your postcode</p>";
//This condition work


}


else if (preg_match('(^[0-9]{4}$)',$value))
{
//This condition is not working
echo "The post code must be a 4-digit number.";
}

else 
{
//This condition working
$json = file_get_contents('http://www.example/API?pcode='.$value[0].'');
```

Comment: whats in `$_POST['search']` ?

Comment: It is form value  <input type="text" name="search" id="txtSearch" value=""   ><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Search"/><br />

Comment: then where is the post code to evaluate?

Comment: It has already in my top php code if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$value=(explode(",",$_POST['search']));

Comment: but what are you exploding, why the preg_split? which returns an array so your use of $value after that is not going to work.

Comment: preg_split using form have to type number and display echo "only type numbers"

Comment: i have no idea that last comment means. BUT. if you check the value of $value after preg_split you will find its an array. so for the empty and regular expression check you probably want `$value[0]` not `$value`

Comment: I am not quit sure, do I need use array for the preg_match?

Comment: preg_split (no idea why your using it) returns an array

Comment: I am using for preg_split check (empty($value) If I comment $value = preg_split() line it' wont check empty values. Are any other function for both, number of digits(4) , only type numbers and empty field check?

Comment: i'll write you an answer just tell me what you get in `$_POST['search']` add `echo $_POST['search'];` so i can see what your working with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

until you comment back, im going with this approach:

```
<?php
$_POST['search'] = '1234'; //used for testing
$post_code = $_POST['search'];


if (empty($post_code)){
    echo "<p>Please type your postcode</p>";
}else if (!preg_match('#[0-9]{4}#',$post_code)){
    echo "The post code must be a 4-digit number.";
}else{
    $json = file_get_contents("http://www.example/API?pcode=$post_code");
}
```

Comment: Thank for your code. Now it display whatever type in text box or even submit null 'The post code must be a 4-digit number. '

Comment: if you change the value above to blank or 'fish' it will echo correctly - that is detect its not a 4 digit number. try it: http://codepad.viper-7.com/2FMikp <<go to link um-comment out 3 examples one at a time - it works

Comment: Are there any missing here $value=(explode(",",$_POST['search'])); because if I remove explode, it'll display all API data list only check (empty($value)) no any check preg_match

Comment: the result of explode is an array, not a string

Comment: can you just provide the answer of the one question i asked to be able to make any sense of this  what is the value of `$_POST['search']` ?

Comment: please refer my temp url http://www.naturalbluesapphires.com/test  $_POST['search']  value equal in Post value

Comment: ok so its going to be a string, i dont understand the explode - and again go to the demo i set up it works

Comment: explode directly fetch parts of the result into variables

Comment: please go to my temp url type any NSW any post code ex. 2000, 2029, 2046 values print why not working?

Comment: sooooooo you want to accept multiple postcodes now ?

Comment: If I type 2, 20, 200 will check number digits. When you type 2000 it will display all API data list even start with 3, 4 all. What do I have to do display only 2000 post code?

Comment: Thank you for your help, well done. I found mistake is .$value[0].

Answer (score 0):

Check Wikipedia For Australian Postal Code Formula-->

ACT: 0200-0299 and 2600-2639.

NSW: 1000-1999, 2000-2599 and 2640-2914.

NT: 0900-0999 and 0800-0899.

QLD: 9000-9999 and 4000-4999.

SA: 5000-5999.

TAS: 7800-7999 and 7000-7499.

VIC: 8000-8999 and 3000-3999.

WA: 6800-6999 and 6000-6799

Regular Expression: ^(0[289][0-9]{2})|([1345689][0-9]{3})|(2[0-8][0-9]{2})|(290[0-9])|(291[0-4])|(7[0-4][0-9]{2})|(7[8-9][0-9]{2})$

Pass: 0200|||7312|||2415

Fail: 0300|||7612|||2915